# Spring-hibernate-maven webapp error (CLASSNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I built my proj with "Dynamic Web App", converted it to Maven proj.
When starting app on Tomcat 8, there is an issue:

Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext      resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested    exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as  in the configuration.

There are my files:

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">



<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.junta"/>  


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>        
    <mapping class="com.junta.model.User"/>
</session-factory>         
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebApp2</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-  class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

**Here is stack trace from Tomcat:**

```
апр 10, 2016 4:13:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
апр 10, 2016 4:13:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
апр 10, 2016 4:13:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4206 ms
апр 10, 2016 4:14:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Sun Apr 10 16:14:30 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17877c8: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,viewResolver,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17877c8: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,viewResolver,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.junta.model.User"/> in the configuration:
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.junta.model.User"/> in the configuration:
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1002)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1440)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:978)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:642)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.junta.model.User
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:635)
    ... 48 more
апр 10, 2016 4:14:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.junta.model.User"/> in the configuration:
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.junta.model.User"/> in the configuration:
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1002)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1440)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:978)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:642)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.junta.model.User
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:635)
    ... 48 more

апр 10, 2016 4:14:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.junta.model.User
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:635)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1002)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1440)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:978)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:642)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The class app required is **com.junta.model.User**
   I tried change mapping class but it didn't resolve my issue.
I have read about CLASSPATH, may be I need change smth in setup?

Comment: Is this the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710047/mavenspringhibernate-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-co

Comment: @Springgrass I don't sure. I think the problem is in class path or something like this. In xml files all paths typed correct..

Comment: Are you sure that you have class `com.junta.model.User` ? If yes, then are you sure that `User` class is added in WAR classpath as well? To view your class in WAR files, open your WAR using Archive Manager or Winrar etc, see whether you see this file or not: `<your-war>/WEB-INF/classes/com/junta/model/User.class`

Comment: @xsalefter yes, I just checked..

Comment: @xsalefter is this normal if I have those paths: WebApp2.war\WEB-INF\classes\WEB-INF\classes\ ? There are empty

Comment: No it's not. I think you should fix that and see what happened.

Comment: @xsalefter ahhaha, how can I fix this?)

Comment: @xsalefter may be issue in Deployment Assembly? What it should be like?

Comment: @RamonDekkers try to put your pom.xml here. Furthermore, try to find out how [maven project structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and [maven WAR plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) work.